# Peer failed to perform TLS handshake when adding Google account to online accounts

Tags: online-accounts, tls

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. When I try to connect the Google account to the online account, I encounter the following error:

> Peer failed to perform TLS handshake: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have this problem in the Mint linux